# Plotly subplots with shared legend in R

Tags: r, legend, r-plotly

I have made twoplots using plotly, which are working fine individually, but when combined using subplot I can't seem to figure out how to combine the legends. I have tried to use showlegend = F in plot_ly in one of the plots, but this just removes it completely - what I want is to control both subplots with the same legend.

My code is as follows:

```
coronavirus_not_china <- coronavirus %>%
  filter(!(country == "China"))

cases_not_china_plot <- coronavirus_not_china %>% 
  group_by(type, date) %>%
  summarise(total_cases = sum(cases)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = total_cases) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(active = confirmed - death - recovered) %>%
  mutate(active_total = cumsum(active),
                recovered_total = cumsum(recovered),
                death_total = cumsum(death)) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~ date,
                  y = ~ active_total,
                  name = 'Active', 
                  fillcolor = '#1f77b4',
                  type = 'scatter',
                  mode = 'none', 
                  stackgroup = 'one',
                  showlegend = F) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~ death_total, 
             name = "Death",
             fillcolor = '#E41317') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~recovered_total, 
            name = 'Recovered', 
            fillcolor = 'forestgreen') %>%
  layout(title = "Distribution of Covid19 Cases outside China",
         legend = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.9),
         yaxis = list(title = "Number of Cases", showgrid = T))
```

```
coronavirus_china <- coronavirus %>%
  filter((country == "China"))

cases_china_plot <- coronavirus_china %>% 
  group_by(type, date) %>%
  summarise(total_cases = sum(cases)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = total_cases) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(active = confirmed - death - recovered) %>%
  mutate(active_total = cumsum(active),
                recovered_total = cumsum(recovered),
                death_total = cumsum(death)) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~ date,
                  y = ~ active_total,
                  name = 'Active', 
                  fillcolor = '#1f77b4',
                  type = 'scatter',
                  mode = 'none', 
                  stackgroup = 'one',
                  showlegend = T) %>%
  add_trace(y = ~ death_total, 
             name = "Death",
             fillcolor = '#E41317') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~recovered_total, 
            name = 'Recovered', 
            fillcolor = 'forestgreen') %>%
  layout(title = "Distribution of Covid19 Cases inside China",
         legend = list(x = 0.1, y = 0.9),
         yaxis = list(title = "Number of Cases", showgrid = F))
```

And I create the subplots as:

```
subplot(cases_not_china_plot, cases_china_plot, nrows = 2, margin = 0.05, shareX = T) %>%
  layout(title="Coronavirus cases outside China and in China", ylab("Number of cases"))
```

I am quite new to R, so if there is a smarter way to do what I desire, please let me know.
With the above code, my output is:

[image: subplots with plotly]

Answer (score 0):

You need 'legendgroup'.
I have built this example as you don't mention the source of your data:

```
fig1 <- plot_ly(x=c('A','B'), y=c(1,2), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', 
                line=list(color = 'red'), name = 'First', legendgroup = 1) %>% 
  add_trace(y=c(5,5), line=list(color = 'blue'), name = 'Second', legendgroup = 2)

fig2 <- plot_ly(x=c('A','B'), y=c(2,1), type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', 
                line=list(color = 'red'), name = 'First', legendgroup = 1, showlegend = F) %>% 
  add_trace(y=c(3,3), line=list(color = 'blue'), name = 'Second', legendgroup = 2, showlegend = F)

subplot(fig1, fig2, nrows = 2)
```

This renders:
[image]

Assigning the same legendgroup 1 or 2 (could be any name or number) respectively lets you control the traces with only one legend entry.
You (can) hide the legend of the 2nd plot with 'showlegend = F'.